# PsExec - Can't Find Specific Path

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, pstools

I'm trying to install a `msi` file using PsExec from a network path but I get an error saying `The system can't find that path specified.`

I'm not sure why it's happening - if there's an error in my code or what the problem is. You can see that `.bat` file code, the properties with location of the file that causing the error as well as the error in the screenshot below.

[image]

So what I'm asking is: why is this not working? (I have checked my permissions and they're all fine.)

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote but you could a least xplain so I know what i can do better next time

Comment: A few guesses are: spelling / presentation lacks effort; no evidence that you've researched the issue; the fact that you then ask further basic questions implies you expect the community to hand it to you on a plate, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the error in the console open by psexec you can see that UNC paths are not supported...

so... you cannot use paths like \...

Just map a drive to the share you want to use... 
then invoke the *.msi from the mapped drive... et voilá!!! c'est fini!!!

instead of : "psexec \\\.msi"
map the drive to the path : net use \\ x: /user:
then use : "psexec x:\.msi"

Comment: Can I do this from a batch file cause it runs at login

Comment: also it getting stuck on accepting the terms in the installation of my program how can i bypass taht

Comment: @apples If you need an unattended installation of some product you should really speak to the folks who make that product (if it's your product, produce a custom MSI :-)

Comment: You can move the mapping and psexec executions to batch file... no problem...

Comment: for automatic accepting terms you should use the /accepteula switch with psexec...
I know there was a problem with this switch in version previous than 1.85 of psexec... but that was a long ago... any way... check your version!